# How to combine two data frames where only one column is same in two data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, aggregate, bind

DF1 is

```
No ID
2  5678
3  3241
5  8167
```

DF2 is

```
 NO Name meaning
  1   a    aaple
  2   b    bat
  3   c    cat
  4   d    dam
  5   e    egg
```

I want to combine DF1 AND DF2 to DF3(this contains all the columns from DF1 and DF2)

expected ouput DF3 is

```
      No Name meaning  ID
      1   a    aaple
      2   b    bat    5678
      3   c    cat    3241
      4   d    dam
      5   e    egg    8167
```

I tried using cbind, but R is giving an error 'Process failed. Script terminated abnormally'

Then i used 'merge' function, but the result is

```
  No Name meaning  ID
  2   b    bat    5678
  3   c    cat    3241
  5   e    egg    8167
```

Please let me know if i am wrong in using functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify `all` parameter to be TRUE if you want to keep all records. Have a look at `?merge`, by default, `all, all.x` and `all.y` are set to be FALSE and it is an inner join:

```
merge(df1, df2, by = "No", all = T)

#   No   ID Name meaning
# 1  1   NA    a   aaple
# 2  2 5678    b     bat
# 3  3 3241    c     cat
# 4  4   NA    d     dam
# 5  5 8167    e     egg
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this command

```
df3 <- merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "No", all = TRUE)
```

or if you are operating on bigger data sets, dplyrs inner_join() function is much faster

```
library(dplyr)
df3 <- inner_join(df2,df1,by = "no")
```

Comment: For OP's desired output, `left_join` is needed not `inner_join`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `match` from `base R` to do this and it should be very efficient

```
DF3 <- DF2
DF3$ID <- DF1$ID[match(DF2$NO, DF1$No)]
DF3
#  NO Name meaning   ID
#1  1    a   aaple   NA
#2  2    b     bat 5678
#3  3    c     cat 3241
#4  4    d     dam   NA
#5  5    e     egg 8167
```

---

Or we can use join with `on` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF1)[DF2, on = c("No" = "NO")]
#    No   ID Name meaning
#1:  1   NA    a   aaple
#2:  2 5678    b     bat
#3:  3 3241    c     cat
#4:  4   NA    d     dam
#5:  5 8167    e     egg
```